# Separate actions in different programs

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use separate ahk-actions in Chrome and Notepad. So that !e in chrome would do one thing, and !e in Notepad would do another. And !e in a third program would do a third action.

Do I make this with IfWinActive?

I'm a newbie to ahk, and not a programmer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
   Space::TrayTip,, % "first action"
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe notepad.exe
   Space::TrayTip,, % "second action"
#IfWinActive
   Space::TrayTip,, % "third action"
```

Comment: I had no idea about `ahk_exe` after all this time! Kudos!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I googled for ahk_exe and I did not get it (or arrived at a bad explanation).