# Typed string to trigger action

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I asked a question called [Separate actions in different programs](https://superuser.com/questions/628744/separate-actions-in-different-programs/628791?iemail=1&noredirect=1#628791) and got an answer.

But then, I tried to make another myself. Did not go so well.

a) this works

```
:*:note::
send {delete}
run notepad.exe
return
```

b) this does not work

```
:*:note::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Notepad++
    WinActivate, Notepad++
    send {delete}
    run notepad.exe
else
    WinActivate, 
return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:*:note::
   SetTitleMatchMode, 2
   IfWinExist, % "Notepad++"
   {
      WinActivate, % "Notepad++"
      SendEvent, {Del}
      Run, % "notepad.exe"
   }
   Else
   {
      TrayTip, % "Error", % "Notepad++ is not exist!",, 3
      Sleep, 1000
      TrayTip
   }
   Return
```

Comment: Typing *note* does not trigger any action.

Comment: This works for me.